Opening links in plugin card
We are using the plugin bridge to open links within the card face and are looking for clarification on some of the items listed here: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/
Specifically, the documentation says that links with a _blank attribute are opened in as an "embedded web browser link" using the "SFSafariViewController". It also provides a warning that these links would be unauthenticated. We understood the link opening as an embedded web browser using the view controller as the link would open inside of the app in a web view which does not seem to be the case. When using _blank, the link leaves the app and opens a new mobile browser tab; it is not embedded in the app. This link (after leaving the app for the mobile browser) is unauthenticated as expected.
When clicking the same link using _top attribute, the link is opened inside of the app (like what is shown in the animated screenshots), and remains authenticated.
To confirm, is the expected behavior that _blank links leave the app and open in the mobile browser unauthenticated (not in an embedded web view) while _top links open inside of the app in an embedded web view and remain authenticated. That seems to be what is happening in real life testing.
Secondly, when opening an external link inside of the app web view (using _top) does that view have the same restrictions as the plugin card itself (sandbox iframe) or is that different? What is required to have links (that may be to other external sites) work from the embedded browser view? Currently, when the external page is opened in the web view from the plugin card (using _top) links within the external page that have the _blank attribute do not work. We would expect they would leave the app and open those links in the mobile browser (which is what happens in the plugin card itself).

I'm looking into this and shared this with the engineering team to debug.
